# Deleting specific symbols inside file

Tags: linux

I have a problem. I have a file in this format:

```
Hi / Tom /
Be / Nice /
...
```

And I need to delete "/" and " "(space) and sort it

```
Be Nice
Hi Tom
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for sorted_word in $(for word in $(sed  -e 's/\/ //g' path_to_file); do printf "%s\n" ${word}; done | sort); do printf "%s " ${sorted_word}; done ; printf "%s\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `tr` command like

```
cat inputfile.txt | tr -s "\/" "" | tr " " "\n" | sort | tr "\n" " "
```

Comment: `cat ./1 | tr  -s  ' \/ ' ' ' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort  | tr '\n' ' '; printf "%n"` works for me, but not your solution @Rahul

Comment: @user1641854, do you get any error while running the command (OR) it's not giving expected result?

Comment: gives error: "tr: when not truncating set1, string2 must be non-empty"